# the sequence of If statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, random

https://codepen.io/quanahquan/pen/qmvYEq?editors=1010

```
var resultArray = [];

function pickRandom(){
  var min = parseInt(document.getElementById("min").value);
  var max = parseInt(document.getElementById("max").value);
    var result = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);
     if (resultArray.includes(result))
      {
        pickRandom();
      }
     if (resultArray.length === max)
      {
        alert("you ran out of number");
      }
     else
      {
        resultArray.push(result);
        document.getElementById("result").value = result;
      }
  }
```

hi guys... I can't understand the logic behind this

I have 2 IFs statements, but in this case if I put the resultArray.length === max IF statement in second, it will result in undesirable result such as being triggered before all 48 numbers were randomly picked

if I put the resultArray.length === max IF statement first, then it will pick all 48 numbers before alerting...

Comment: Put all the code in the question, shouldn't it be else if instead of else?

Comment: I just did, thanks, but how it may be else if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my mind, this algorithm is not efficient. For large numbers, it will spend large amount of time to find missing gaps. Imagine `max` is 1,000,000 and the algorithm generated 999,999 numbers so far. It'll keep producing random numbers until it manager to find the missing one and that will take a lot of time.

I updated your code to make it work using recursive calls. It's meant for learning, not to be used in real application.

```
var resultArray = [];

function pickRandom() {
    // Warning: min and max should't change between calls
    var min = parseInt(document.getElementById("min").value);
    var max = parseInt(document.getElementById("max").value);

    // result is in the interval [min, max]
    var result = Math.round((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);

    // Do we have too many items in resultArray?
    if (resultArray.length === max - min + 1)
    {
        alert("you ran out of number");
    }
    else if (resultArray.includes(result))
    {
        // Already chosen, pick another number
        // Warning: going recursive is not efficient
        pickRandom();
    } else {
        // Is a new number. Store it and show it.
        resultArray.push(result);
        document.getElementById("result").value = result;
    }
  }
```

Some of the errors you had in your code:

- Computing result was wrong, the correct way is `Math.round((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min)`
- Correct test for detecting when the all the values were used: `(resultArray.length === max - min + 1)`, in your code you forgot to substract min
- In your code, the second `if` executes no matter what happens in the first one. Therefore, it'll add a value to resultArray even if it was already found in that array.

Answer (score 0):

You have two inputs **min** and **max**. You also make an array list - **resultArray**. Every time when you pick a lucky number it checks if the number is in that list. At the beginning it doesn't enter in the first **if** at all, because it is empty or the chance to get the same number is very low. Actually you do not need that first **if** statement because it does what your onclick event call do.

The second **if** statement checks if the length is equals to the max value. If it is, then you can't pick more lucky numbers and get alert everytime.